# How to fill a field with comboBox.currentText()

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, pyqt5, combo-box

Basically, I want to create a widget plugin (QGIS 3.x) in which any user can choose a standard text from a combo box and, after press a ok button, enable a layer for editing and calls the add feature tool and fill's the ***obs*** field of the new feature with the chosen currentText from the combo box.

[image]

I've already made the core code of the plugin and it works, but, ***I dont have any idea*** how can I put the chosen combo box text in the field. I thought in e a function that fills the ***obs*** field with a *qgsexpression* or a put *qgsfunction* in expression dialog but not seens to me the right way.

```py
...
from .src.manager import Handler
from .rev_env_dockwidget import revEnvDockWidget


def run(self):

 if not self.pluginIsActive:
  self.pluginIsActive = True

   if self.dockwidget == None:
    self.dockwidget = revEnvDockWidget()

   self.dockwidget.closingPlugin.connect(self.onClosePlugin)
   self.iface.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.dockwidget)
   self.dockwidget.show()
   self.dockwidget.hookComboBox.clear()
   self.dockwidget.hookComboBox.addItems(Handler.hookCombo(self))
   self.dockwidget.hookPushButton.clicked.connect(self.begEdit)
   canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()

def begEdit(self):
 layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('aux_revisao_p')[0]
 layer.startEditing()
 self.iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
 self.iface.actionAddFeature().trigger()
```

Anyone can point me a way?

Comment: Please do not delete and repost questions. SE has automated defense mechanisms which will be activated if you make a habit of this.

Comment: The question is vague, many way to do tha in Python. It depends how you created your code, how you open the second window. Can you show us?

Comment: Yes, sure @etrimaille.

Comment: Sorry @Vince, I just want to put the question without errors.

Comment: Questions (and answers) with errors are common, and edits are a good thing.

Comment: Oh so the window on the left in the feature form generated by QGIS when you add an attribute? his wasn't obvious. Did you consider having the combobox in the QGIS form attribute instead? Would it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it's wasn't clear, sorry. The window on the left appears when the user clicks to create a new feature. A combobox in the attribute field is not working because we have a fixed database modeling that does not accept an attribute field like combobox.